# Send midi output from an iOS app to Garageband

Tags: ios, swift, midi, audiokit

How can one send midi output from an iPad app to Garageband, like [Skoog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FnPUWDB10g) does? I do not want to create an audio unit extension, just to be able to send midi notes (from the initial app when in background mode).

Is this possible using AudioKit? I have found no documentation of such kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, AudioKit is a great choice for sending MIDI to other apps.

What are you trying to send?

If you're trying to send full sequences of notes and data, here's a working app store example, and a reference: 
https://audiokitpro.com/chordbud-and-midi-code/

Additionally, the AudioKit powered repo, *MIDI Sequencer - Sends MIDI events to other apps*, by Cem Olcay may be of interest to you: https://github.com/cemolcay/MIDISequencer

At a simpler level, if you want to send MIDI out of an app, you can create a virtual port and send the output using AKMIDI. You can open the midi output as follows:

```
let midi = AKMIDI() 
midi.openOutput()
```